# ssis - flat file source - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

Am attempting to use SSIS flat file source to read a log file being actively written to.  Looping and waiting for the file to be released is not practical as this is an active log file held by a service.

Ideally, I'm looking for a setting upon the flat file source, similar to the C# code below.  If not that, what route can I take to read the flat file?  I'm attempting to stay within SSIS as I sincerely can't believe this can't be done with stock parts and assume I'm just missing something.

Using C#, I can successfully open the exact file upon which the flat file source errors

```
System.IO.FileStream file
= new System.IO.FileStream
    (
        file_to_hash.FullName
        , System.IO.FileMode.Open
        , System.IO.FileAccess.Read
        , System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite
    );
```

This is the error message experienced in SSIS:
Warning: 0x80070020 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [1]: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Error: 0xC020200E at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [1]: Cannot open the datafile "XXX".

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to use a File System Task to make a copy of the file first, and then use the copy as the flat file source? I don't think it should have any trouble copying the in-use file, but I didn't try it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

both ideas by tim and cade would work.  I chose Tim's approach - copying the file b/c I already had the code ( both the copy and the data tranformation ), and changing the name/path of the file going into the data transformation was a configuration setting of the app being built.  Wish I could mark it answered, but asked the question as an unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a custom data source - [possibly as simple as a script task](http://www.ssistalk.com/2007/04/04/ssis-using-a-script-component-as-a-source/).